# Intergrate libcreate into create_autonomy CMakeList change

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cloned libcreate into my workspace and did catkin_make_isolated.

I want to make changes to the create_autonomy package through intergrating libcreate with it.

I was wondering if I need to change anything in the create_autonomy CMakeList or package.xml after building the libcreate

like maybe instead of:

```
include_directories(
    include
 ${libcreate_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 )
```

it's :

```
include_directories(
  include
  /home/<name>/catkin_ws/src/libcreate/include/create
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328789/intergrate-libcreate-into-create_autonomy-cmakelist-change/) by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-07-17**:
Please be more specific about what you are trying to do. As it is, you haven't really asked a question that people can answer.

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-07-17**:
@Geoff ok I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you don't need to do anything other than put the `create_autonomy` package in your workspace.

See [this document](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) for an explanation of what you are doing (overlaying a package) and how to do it.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-07-18**:
oh so the libcreate in my workspace will override the other?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-07-22**:\

> oh so the libcreate in my workspace will override the other?

Yes, it should prefer the version built from source.

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-07-25**:
Great! Thank you! Geoff and jacobperron

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-07-29**:
can i have libcreate in another workspace?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2019-08-04**:
You can provided you source the workspaces in the correct order. The more workspaces you chain, the harder it gets to maintain orderings, though.